# understanding canvas arc parameters

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wa just messing aroud with the basics of canvas and i see the initial 2 paramters to draw an arc in can are the `x` and `y` , saw an example like below:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JS code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Now my question is , is the x and y coordinates relative to the document ?

Comment: Nope, the x,y is the **arc's centerpoint relative to the canvas origin (origin == [0,0] by default)**. If you have applied transformations, then x,y will be altered by transformations.